How to Add Margin to my-select Based on Sibling Element in StencilJS
I’m working with custom StencilJS custom components, specifically my-select and my-input, which are frequently used together within a <div class="form"></div>. However, there are scenarios where these components are used independently.
Here are some details:

my-input includes a transparent paragraph element for displaying error messages.
my-select and my-input can be swapped or used interchangeably.
my-select has shadow: false.

I need to add a bottom margin to my-select when it is followed by my-input or another my-select in the DOM. For instance, if the structure is:
<div class="form">
    <my-select></my-select>
    <my-input></my-input>
</div>

I know this may sound very easy, and maybe there is something I am not noticing, but I want to apply a bottom margin to the my-select component.
I’ve tried various CSS selectors and combinations, including:
The adjacent sibling combinator (+);
The :has pseudo-class;
However, these approaches have not worked for me. For instance:
:host {
  & + my-input {
    margin-bottom: rem(28px);
  }
}
or 
:host + my-input {
    margin-bottom: rem(28px);
  }
}
or
my-select + my-input {
    margin-bottom: rem(28px);
}

As a workaround, I’ve used:
:host-context(.form) {
  margin-bottom: rem(28px);
}

But I’m curious if there are more efficient or alternative solutions that leverage sibling selectors or other CSS techniques.
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

This can be done by using :has() pseudo-class Selector & + Adjacent Sibling Selector.


.my-select:has( + .my-input),
.my-select:has( + .my-select) {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
<div class="form">
  <div class="my-select">
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="my-input">
    <p>Paragraph 2</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form">
  <div class="my-select">
    <p>Paragraph 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="my-select">
    <p>Paragraph 4</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form">
  <div class="my-input">
    <p>Paragraph 5</p>
  </div>
  <div class="my-select">
    <p>Paragraph 6</p>
  </div>
</div>




I have tried with :has as well, maybe my syntax was incorrect, I'll try once again with your syntax now, thank you

Unfortunately, this solution did not work for me.
I see that you are using the component names as classes, I use component names like my-select:has( + my-select){}, I hope that's not a problem

@LilitMazmanyan, I am not sure but you can try with class name onces & check it's work or not.
